# Perl: Can't install/use CPAN modules

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm trying to code a litte RSS Parser in perl. Just as simple as possible.
To parse a rss feed (e.g. www.rssfeedhomepage.com/rssfeed.xml) I want to use a module from the CPAN Homepage, because it's much easer than create an own one.
But I'm not able to install it. I tryied it using the shell ( "perl -MCPAN -e shell") and manually (unzip, install, make) but it didn't work out. I tried it with severals RSS modules but everytime the same problem. Do you have any ideas?
I'm using ubuntu linux as a VM on Windows 7.

Thanks!

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. Why did it fail? Did you get some error messages for instance? Oh, is the module really named "shell"? And the correct format for the command is perl -MCPAN -e "install <modulename>".

Comment: Nobody can tell you how to fix your problem when you don't tell us any details of the problem. "didn't work out" is no more useful than telling a doctor "it hurts". What did you do, what did you expect to see, what did you see?

Comment: @Makis — The module isn't called shell, that runs the CPAN shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest using the awesome cpanminus tool to install a module from CPAN:

First install cpanminus itself:

```
$ curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus
```

Then install whathever module you want like the following:

```
$ sudo cpanm Some::Module
```

cpanminus should work out of the box, it's a zeroconf tool written by Tatsuhiko Miyagawa

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. this programm looks really nice. But if I try to run my programm now (after installing XML::RSS::Parser::Lite) I get such error:

Comment: Can't locate XML/Parser/Lite.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/XML/RSS/Parser/Lite.pm line 42.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/XML/RSS/Parser/Lite.pm line 42.
Compilation failed in require at test.py line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.py line 1.

Comment: Check if you have XML::Parser::Lite installed in one of those locations. If you have, check permissions. If not, install the package.

Comment: hey, thanks man!! This works! You've been really helpful. BTW, nice web framework!